# Is it possible to reset a value in a TextField-Component to its initial value with js/react without deep copies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to implement a table with editable cells. After editing, the cell should a) reset to its initial value, if I click somewhere on the screen, or b) save the edited value if I hit enter.

This question concerns only a) i.e. restoring the initial value.

[Working App (stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-x1fuvx?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

I figured out that I have to use onBlur to handle the loss of focus. Moreover, it looks like it's necessary to make a deep copy of newFruits every time I want to reset the edited cell. If I do a shallow copy, everytime I modify newFruits, fruits is modified too.

The deep copy using JSON.parse looks cumbersome to me. Is there an easier way of achieving the same behaviour?

```
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);
  const [newFruits, setNewFruits] = useState([]);
```

```
<TextField
  value={newFruits[index].fruit}
  size="small"
  onBlur={() => handleBlur(index)}
  onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
></TextField>
```

```
const handleBlur = (index) => {
    const blurFruits = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newFruits));
    blurFruits[index].fruit = fruits[index].fruit;
    setNewFruits(blurFruits);
  };
```

```
  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const updateFruits = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newFruits));
    updateFruits[index].fruit = event.target.value;
    setNewFruits(updateFruits);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make an entire copy, you can just project the array into a new array with only a new copy of the element that has to change.  For example:

```
const handleBlur = (index) => {
  setNewFruits(newFruits.map((f, i) => 
    i === index ? { ...f, fruit: fruits[index].fruit } : f
  );
};

const handleChange = (event, index) => {
  setNewFruits(newFruits.map((f, i) => 
    i === index ? { ...f, fruit: event.target.value } : f
  );
};
```

So for example if `newFruits` has 100 array elements, 99 of them are unchanged here.  `.map()` returns a new array instance, but that array contains 99 of the same references to the same unchanged objects.  Only one new object is created at the matching `index` to replace the previous object at that index.  (Ideally you'd use a unique identifier on the object itself, but if your logic currently uses the positional index than this continues to do the same.)